# javascript preloader in pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, livecycle

I have a pdf form that contains no images but lots of javascript to format the answer fields (validation, section generation etc). This slows the pdf down when it's opening in acrobat to the point where it takes a full 25 seconds for the user to see the first page of the form.

Is there any way I can set up the pdf to show a preloader whilst it's opening that gives the user the information to show that the form is being set up to be filled in?

Additional info:
The form is being composed in LiveCycle.
It's not being filled in online (so no use for a web page preloader) and will be downloaded before being opened, filled in and printed out to be returned to me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a pre-loader for livecycle forms but what you may want to look at is moving some of the validation to the Form:Ready event or similar.

The validate event is called numerous times on form load eg. as the object loads, the subform it is contained in and the page.

You should analyse when you want the validation to take place and trigger it then rather than rely purely on the validate event.

I have found that creating functions to carry out the validation and calling those rather than entering the script directly into the event is also quicker as it reduces the size of the form.